# How to set filename and commit encoding in cvs client

Tags: cvs

In CVS for eclipse plugin there is "Server Encoding" property, but in normal `cvs` command is not.

How can i specify encoding to use?

I'm trying convert cvs repo to git, using cygwin's version of both. In eclipse filenames and comments shows normally when "server encoding" is "cp1251"

In cygwin environment, LANG variable change has no effect.

In cvs man page there is no references of "encoding", "codepage" or something similiar

```
$ cvs --version
Concurrent Versions System (CVS) 1.12.13 (client/server)
```

If i extract cvs log with `cvs rlog` filename command and then pass it to iconv -f -t then it's displayed correctly. This proof that there is some way of extract this information.

Looks like git cvsimport uses cvsps output and provides some way to pass options to cvsps. Next question is - how i can tell cvsps to convert output? maybe i should youse some cvsps wrapper insted of real cvsps? or some sort of temporary patchset storage?